# SXA Calendar Events Documention

Tags: sxa

Is there complete documentation on the Events List and Calendar List for SXA, and in particular the Events Type field and how to setup where it looks for event types, or can the event list headings be types.

Comment: Have you tried this https://doc.sitecore.com/users/sxa/18/sitecore-experience-accelerator/en/add-an-event-calendar-and-an-event-list-rendering.html ?

Answer (score 2):

The SXA documentation unfortunately makes no mention of the Event Types field. I had to dig into the code to figure out what it was doing as the source field is pointing at `code:Sitecore.XA.Feature.Events.CodeDataSource.EventTypes, Sitecore.XA.Feature.Events`

Each Event List item you create has an Event Types drop down on it:

[image: Event Type]

This is linked to the node in the Presentation section which allows you to set styles against an event:

[image: Event Type Styles]